# ArangoDb - How to count number of filtered results before limiting them

Tags: filter, pagination, limit, arangodb, aql

```
db.query(aql `
   FOR doc IN ${collection} 
     FILTER REGEX_TEST(CONCAT(VALUES(doc, true)), ${queryStr}, true)
       SORT doc[${sortBy}] ${dir}
         LIMIT ${start, count} 
           RETURN doc._key
        `)
        .then(cursor => {
            cb(cursor._result)
        }, err => console.log(err))
```

I have above AQL query,
I want to count total nuber of filtered results before limiting the results per page (For Pagination Purpose)

I think issue is similar to this [MySQL - How to count rows before pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570508/mysql-how-to-count-rows-before-pagination), [Find total number of results in mySQL query with offset+limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928611/find-total-number-of-results-in-mysql-query-with-offsetlimit)

want to do in ArangoDb with AQL

and part of solution may be this [How to count number of elements with AQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077048/how-to-count-number-of-elements-with-aql)

So, What is the efficient/best solution for my requirement with AQL ?

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Comment: One more help please.. :) would you please give me a minimal example for  how to acheive the above using ArangoJS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the flag `fullCount` in the *options* for creating the cursor to true. Then the result will have an extra attribute with the sub-attributes `stats` and `fullCount`.

You then can get the the `fullCount`-attribute via `cursor.extra.stats.fullCount`. This attribute contains the number of documents in the result before the last `LIMIT` in the query was applied. [see HTTP documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/current/HTTP/AqlQueryCursor/AccessingCursors.html)

In addition, you should use the [explain feature](https://docs.arangodb.com/current/AQL/ExecutionAndPerformance/ExplainingQueries.html) to analyse your query. In your case, your query will always make a full collection scan, thus won't scale well.

**update**

I added the fullCount flag to your code. Keep in mind, that the `fullCount` attribute only appears if the number of results before `LIMIT` is higher then the results after.

```
db.query(aql ` 
  FOR doc IN ${collection} 
    FILTER REGEX_TEST(CONCAT(VALUES(doc, true)), ${queryStr}, true)
      SORT doc[${sortBy}] ${dir}
        LIMIT ${start, count} 
          RETURN {family: doc.family, group: doc.group} `, {count:true, options:{fullCount:true} })
.then(cursor => { console.log(cursor) }, err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: One more help please.. :) would you please give me a minimal example for how to acheive the above using ArangoJS

Comment: How can i set flags in this..  db.query(aql `
               FOR doc IN ${collection} 
                  FILTER REGEX_TEST(CONCAT(VALUES(doc, true)), ${queryStr}, true)
                    SORT doc[${sortBy}] ${dir}
                     LIMIT ${start, count} 
                      RETURN {family: doc.family, group: doc.group}
            `, {count:true}).then(cursor => {
            console.log(cursor)
        }, err => console.log(err))

Comment: How to set count flag for above?

Comment: {count:true} in above code does nothing.. :( So what is the correct way to set flag and get fullcount from above code...?

Comment: the newes version removed the `options` param and instead you can add the `fullCount` just like `count`
for ex: `{count: true, fullCount: true}` as 2nd param of `db.query`